# Возможно ли модифицировать функцию?

Tags: c++, функции, математика, оптимизация, рекурсия

Возможно ли модифицировать функцию **gcf** таким образом, чтобы она вычисляла выражение **а%b**  один раз за вызов. Если возможно, напишите это оптимальное решение.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcf(int a, int b);
int main() {
    int a, b;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Press \"0\" to exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the 1st number: ";
        cin >> a;
         if (a == 0)
            break;
        cout << "Enter the 2nd number: ";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "gcf: " << gcf(a, b) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
int gcf(int a, int b) {
    cout << "gcf(" << a << " " << b << ")=>" << endl;
    if (a % b == 0)
        return b;
    else
        return gcf(b, a % b);
}
```

Comment: Серьезно? Просто сделайте переменную, запишите в нее результат `a % b`, а потом используйте вместо этого выражения. Или еще лучше, вместо создания отдельной переменной, модифицируйте `a`. Она все равно больше нигде не используется.

Comment: А интересно, что означает `gcf`? :)

Comment: gcf - greatest common factor (наибольший общий делитель)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int gcf(int a, int b) { return (a%=b) ? gcf(b,a):b; }
```

Только называется сие - greatest common divisor, **gcd** (и входит в стандартную библиотеку: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd).